# about the state of react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm writing a SPA using Redux to manage my state. There is a logic component connected to the redux store, and it has a child component and it transport the 'posts' state by props to the child component. In the child component's render function:

```
const {onShow,posts} = this.props;
```

It works well; just the posts will change with the redux store. But in its `componentDidMount()` function or construct function the posts will not change with redux store, so how could it happen?

```
componentDidMount(){
   const {posts} = this.props;
   console.log(posts)
}
```

Here are the complete components [code](https://github.com/laoqiren/isomorphic-redux-CNode/tree/master/common/components). It's about the Lists component and Posts component.

Comment: you can get the new props as `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { console.log(nextProps.posts }`

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but I don't know why the posts will not change in componentDidMount function,

Comment: componentDidMount does not trigger on props change, it will only trigger on initial render.https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Because `componentDidMount()` only gets fired when the component is... well, _mounted_ (_i.e._, rendered to the UI). Or such is my interpretation.

Comment: the react router navigate will make the parent logic component remount and then the child will remount,too. And the componentDidMount runs again indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your post, you are wondering about why you are not able to see the reflection of state update inside of componentDidMount().

It's because componentDidMount function is called when instance of a react component is being created and inserted into the DOM. It's called in mounting phase of a react component's lifecycle.

To be able to see your reflections of redux state update, you need to use functions which are called at the update stage such as:

- componentWillReceiveProps()
- componentDidUpdate()
- shouldComponentUpdate()

To get more detailed information, please check component lifecycle documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html